# How to make the UIImageView appear above the MapView

Tags: ios, uiimageview, xcode4.2

I am willing to get the ImageView appear above the MapView because it contains two buttons, however, what ever i did, the MapView still Hiding the UIImageView:

[image]

Comment: How about some Code or IB view hierarchy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a column to your left when you are looking at interface files, that show the objects associated with you .xib. The bottom-most object will be the one that is in front of all the others

Comment: Yeah, that's it, in Xcode 3 i used to have option like `bring to front` in the window menu, but in that version, it's not obvious from the first while?

Comment: If you select your object, and look under Editor>Arrange, then bring to front should be another option for solving this issue

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm used to the concept of having the things on top be the things on top!

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried?:

```
[someView bringSubviewToFront:myImageView];
```

Put this after you added your mapview to your mainview.

Comment: So, it will look something like this: `[self.view bringSubviewToFront:(UIImageView)image.png];`   ??

Comment: if your imageView pointer is names image.png, yes it shall but I suggest naming it differently ;)  
Also if you post a bit of code i'll be more specific for you.